# Show the spinner/loader inside the input tag

Tags: html, css, input, css-animations, css-transitions

I want to show the spinner/loader inside the input tag and loader's position should not change based on screen size.

My complete code :

```
    <html>
    <style>
    input[type=text]{
      position: relative;
      width: 30%;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .loader {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
      border: 4px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 50% ;
      border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      animation: spinner 1s ease infinite;
    }
    
    
    
    @keyframes spinner {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }    
    </style>
    

   <body>   
    <div>
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text"  name="firstname" class="loader" placeholder="Your name"/>    
    </div>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

But all I get is a spinning input field instead of loader inside the field.

Answer (score 1):

You should add some animation resources to your input. You can try:

```
  <html>
    <style>
        input[type=text]{
        position: relative;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .loading {    
        background-color: #ffffff;
        background-image: url("https://i.gifer.com/ZZ5H.gif");
        background-size: 25px 25px;
        background-position:right center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
<body>   
    <div>
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text"  name="firstname" class="loading" placeholder="Your name"/>    
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: Is the same possible without using gif ?

Comment: Yep, you can animate characters with keyframes, like you start to do. You just need some object to manipulate. It can be everything you want. In your example, you manipulate with your input - just replace it with something else

Comment: If I need my loader inside Input how can I replace it ?